# Uninstalling firefox add on

Tags: nsis

I am installing firefox add on in NSIS using -install-global-extension command.
But i don't know how to uninstall that add on in Uninstaller section.
Can anybody tell me the command through which i can uninstall the add on.
Please help me.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A very tricky and simple way is to delete the extension directory ... that's all ...

Use a RMDir /R /REBOOTOK